# PHP to decode JSON array and insert into MYSQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to create a PHP script that decodes a JSON array and insert it into a database. So far i've managed to get the script to insert the first row in the array and nothing else.

What would I need to add to this to get the script to insert all the rows in the array?

Here's the array, ignore "listings", I don't need that data yet (It's quite big):
[json](http://eddb.io/archive/v3/stations.json)
Here's the script:

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$con = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

//select db
$selected = mysql_select_db("ed",$con);

$json_obj = file_get_contents("stations.json");

//convert to stdclass object
$arr = json_decode($json_obj,true);

//store the element values into variables

$id = $arr[0]["id"];
$name = $arr[0]["name"];
$system_id = $arr[0]["system_id"];
$max_landing_pad_size = $arr[0]["max_landing_pad_size"];
$distance_to_star = $arr[0]["distance_to_star"];
$faction = $arr[0]["faction"];
$government = $arr[0]["government"];
$allegiance = $arr[0]["allegiance"];
$state = $arr[0]["state"];
$type = $arr[0]["type"];
$has_blackmarket = $arr[0]["has_blackmarket"];
$has_commodities = $arr[0]["has_commodities"];
$has_refuel = $arr[0]["has_refuel"];
$has_repair = $arr[0]["has_repair"];
$has_rearm = $arr[0]["has_rearm"];
$has_outfitting = $arr[0]["has_outfitting"];
$has_shipyard = $arr[0]["has_shipyard"];

//insert values into mysql database
$sql="INSERT INTO stations (station_id, name, system_id, max_landing_pad_size, distance_to_star, faction, government, allegiance, state, type, has_blackmarket, has_commodities, has_refuel, has_repair, has_rearm, has_outfitting, has_shipyard) 
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$system_id', '$max_landing_pad_size', '$distance_to_star', '$faction', '$government', '$allegiance', '$state', '$type', '$has_blackmarket', '$has_commodities', '$has_refuel', '$has_repair', '$has_rearm', '$has_outfitting', '$has_shipyard')";

if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)) //$con is mysql connection object
{
     die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: if its going to be really big, you could consider another approach, create a query string first which will enable you to create an insert batch, then run it. or create a file then `load data local infile`. thats going to be much faster instead of looping rows one by one insertion

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach

```
$arr = json_decode($json_obj,true);//decode object
foreach($arr as $ar){

            $id = $ar["id"];
            $name = $ar["name"];
            $system_id = $ar["system_id"];
            $max_landing_pad_size = $ar["max_landing_pad_size"];
            $distance_to_star = $ar["distance_to_star"];
            $faction = $ar["faction"];
            $government = $ar["government"];
            $allegiance = $ar["allegiance"];
            $state = $ar["state"];
            $type = $ar["type"];
            $has_blackmarket = $ar["has_blackmarket"];
            $has_commodities = $ar["has_commodities"];
            $has_refuel = $ar["has_refuel"];
            $has_repair = $ar["has_repair"];
            $has_rearm = $ar["has_rearm"];
            $has_outfitting = $ar["has_outfitting"];
            $has_shipyard = $ar["has_shipyard"];

            //insert values into mysql database
            $sql="INSERT INTO stations (station_id, name, system_id, max_landing_pad_size, distance_to_star, faction, government, allegiance, state, type, has_blackmarket, has_commodities, has_refuel, has_repair, has_rearm, has_outfitting, has_shipyard) 
            VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$system_id', '$max_landing_pad_size', '$distance_to_star', '$faction', '$government', '$allegiance', '$state', '$type', '$has_blackmarket', '$has_commodities', '$has_refuel', '$has_repair', '$has_rearm', '$has_outfitting', '$has_shipyard')";

            if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)) //$con is mysql connection object
            {
                 die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
            }

}
```

Comment: PHP seems to throw an error with this: "Notice: Undefined variable: arr in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 17"

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$arr = json_decode($json_obj,true);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO stations (`';

$sql.=  implode('`,`', array_keys( $arr[0] ) );

$sql.= '`) values (\'';

$sql.=  implode('\',\'',  $arr[0]  );

$sql.= '\')';
```

Comment: I get this when it does it: "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 42"

Comment: You need be sure that $arr[0] have all the 'key'=>'values' combinations.

Answer (score 0):

For big amounts of data like in this case, you would want to execute the query just once, or you'll burden your database unnecessarily. For this, you can build your query with all the data being inserted and then execute it, like so:

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json_obj,true);//decode object
$query = "INSERT into stations (station_id, name, system_id, max_landing_pad_size, distance_to_star, faction, government, allegiance, state, type, has_blackmarket, has_commodities, has_refuel, has_repair, has_rearm, has_outfitting, has_shipyard) values ";
foreach($arr as $ar) {    
    $query .= "($ar['id'],$ar['name'],$ar['system_id'],
                $ar['max_landing_pad_size'],$ar['distance_to_star'],$ar['faction'],
                $ar['government'],$ar['allegiance'],$ar['state'],
                $ar['type'],$ar['has_blackmarket'],$ar['has_commodities'],
                $ar['has_refuel'],$ar['has_repair'],$ar['has_rearm'],
                $ar['has_outfitting'],$ar['has_shipyard']),";
}
$query = rtrim(",",$query);
if(!mysql_query($query,$con)) //$con is mysql connection object
{
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

In case you want to know, your original code doesn't work because you're just grabbing the first row from the json ($arr[0]). You need to loop through the data to get all the rows.